# sending recurring task reminder notifications in jbpm 5.4.0.Final

Tags: jbpm

I have a workflow which has several tasks, one of which needs to send recurring reminder notification every day until the task is completed. I am able to send task notification through custom mailer implementation by extending DefaultEscalatedDeadlineHandler. But I am still unable to achieve the recurring notification part. Is there a way to do this in jbpm 5.4.0.Final. I remember this was there in jbpm 4.3 usung repeat attribute of task.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boundary timer event on the task node.

Comment: Thanks kris. I was able to attach boundary timer event to task, but was not sure how to send recurring task reminders using the boundary timer. Can you please guide me or if u have any reference that can help me. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Kris, I was able to attach a email event to the boundary timer event and everything is working fine, but the problem now is, If I restart the tomcat/JBoss server, Timer is not getting triggered anymore. How to attach the timer back after the server restart?